# sending the contents of a file as the text of an email via sh, curl, mailgun

Tags: bash, curl

I have this send_update.sh file which I want to use to send myself emails

What I have below works just fine.

But, I want to change the text to the contents of the file update.txt

I have tried making a variable `var=cat update.txt` and `-F text=$var` but it just gives me an error:

```
"message": "Need at least one of 'text' or 'html' parameters specified"

#!/bin/sh
curl -s --user 'api:key-mykey' \
    http:mail-gun-api
    -F from=...
    -F to=...
    -F subject='Hello My name is here' \
    -F text='First email!'
```

sadly I cannot just use my usual sendmail because google compute engine does not allow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bash scripts, to set a variable as the output of a command you can use:

```
var=$(cat /full/path/to/file/update.txt)
```

If you do this, the contents of the update.txt file are now assigned to the variable `$var`.  You might want to avoid the `$var` variable altogether though, and do something like:

```
-F text=$(cat /full/path/to/file/update.txt)
```

You probably don't need to include the full path to `update.txt` if the file is in your current working directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I just found out that its only printing until the first space in the txt file. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Rorschach That is the result of [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) performed by Bash, before `curl` is being executed with provided arguments. Moreover, there's no need to use `cat` here. Check out `man curl` and search for `-F, --form`, for how to include file's content in a form.

Answer (score 2):

`curl` supports this behavior internally.

Quoted from `man curl` ( curl version 7.48.0):

> ```
>   -F, --form <name=content>
>          (HTTP)  This  lets  curl  emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.
>          This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the  file  name  with
>          the  symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field
>          from a file.
>
>          Example, to send your password file to the server, where 'password' is the name of the form-field to which /etc/passwd will be the input:
>
>          curl -F password=@/etc/passwd www.mypasswords.com
>
>          To read content from stdin instead of a file, use - as the filename. This goes for both @ and < constructs. Unfortunately it does not support reading the file from a named pipe or  similar,  as
>          it needs the full size before the transfer starts.
>
>          You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', in a manner similar to:
>
>          curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" url.com
>
>          or
>
>          curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" url.com
>
>          You can also explicitly change the name field of a file upload part by setting filename=, like this:
>
>          curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" url.com
>
>          If filename/path contains ',' or ';', it must be quoted by double-quotes like:
>
>          curl -F "file=@\"localfile\";filename=\"nameinpost\"" url.com
>
>          or
>
>          curl -F 'file=@"localfile";filename="nameinpost"' url.com
>
>          Note that if a filename/path is quoted by double-quotes, any double-quote or backslash within the filename must be escaped by backslash.
>
>          See further examples and details in the MANUAL.
>
>          This option can be used multiple times.
> ```

## Edit:

OP solved it with `-F text="</path/to/update.txt"` as discussed in the comments.

Comment: Sadly it returns:   "message": "'text' parameter is not a string"

Comment: What to you mean by "it" ? Can I please see what you're executing ?

Comment: As quoted in my answer "*To just get the content part from a file, prefix the  file  name  with
         the  symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field
         from a file.*"

Comment: `-F text=</path/to/update.txt` gives "message": `"Need at least one of 'text' or 'html' parameters specified"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108867/discussion-between-rany-albeg-wein-and-rorschach).

Comment: To read from stdin you can do `-F text="<-"`. The quotes are necessary!